# recursion in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to make this sample program work

```
(defn foo
  ([x] (foo x []))
  ([x current]
     (when (> x 0)
       (recur (dec x) (conj current x)))))
```

When I call this function (foo 5), I should get [1 2 3 4 5], however it only returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have corrected your original program to use `(if (= x 0)` instead of `(when (> x 0)`, and this returns `[1 2 3 4 5]`.

```
(defn foo
  ([x] (foo x []))
  ([x current]
     (if (= x 0)
       (apply vector (sort < current))
       (recur (dec x) (conj current x)))))
```

Comment: Ankur response is better as (foo -1) returns []. Your version will cause a OOM in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Your recursion doesn't have a return expression i.e when then `when` is false the recursion terminates and it returns nil. You can fix this using `if` as:

```
(defn foo
  ([x] (foo x []))
  ([x current]
     (if (> x 0)
       (recur (dec x) (conj current x))
       current)))
```

This will return `[5 4 3 2 1]` for `(foo 5)` as you are using vector as return value and `conj` on vector appends the item at the end of the vector. You can either reverse the vector or use list i.e in place of `(foo x [])` use `(foo x '())`

Comment: I usually prefer the exit condition first, as I find it easier to read.

Comment: Another point of view could be having the return/exit case last as that is most people are used to when looking at some function code in other languages as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The code below works. I was not returning the final value.

```
(defn foo
  ([x] (foo x []))
  ([x current]
     (if (> x 0)
       (recur (dec x) (conj current x))
       current)))
```