# What is the difference between two functions' arguments?

Tags: clojure

I am wondering what the differences -- if any -- in the argument vectors of the following two functions. I believe I understand what is going on intuitively, but the first one caught me off guard. Thank you.

From Stackoverflow [recursion in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995396/recursion-in-clojure/10995576#10995576)

```
(defn foo
  ([x] (foo x []))
  ([x current]
     (if (= x 0)
       (apply vector (sort < current))
       (recur (dec x) (conj current x)))))
```

and one of my own functions

```
(defn strip-csv-header
    "Pulls out first row from csv data. If column definitions, those will
     be removed; else first row of data will be removed."

    [csv-data-all]
    (let [csv-data (rest csv-data-all)]
        csv-data))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` works with either one or two parameters wherein `strip-csv-header` will only function with one parameter.

```
(defn foo
  ([x] (foo x [])) ; one arg path

  ([x current]     ; two args path
     (if (= x 0)
       (apply vector (sort < current))
       (recur (dec x) (conj current x)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So this is a variable argument signature?

Comment: Yep, you can have functions which can be overloaded by number of arguments (arity) like this.

Answer (score 4):

just an addition to Jani Hartikainen's answer:

the third type of function arguments are Variable arity functions:

```
(def bar [ &any-number-of-args ] (map baz any-number-of-args))
```

This is not really part of the original question, just an note for completeness.